# Flutter function doesn't stop after return

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an uber-like flutter app, and I am currently programming the driver search system in my realtimedatabase, I make a query over "driversQueue", sort them by FIFO aproch and iterate over the list, making a validation that the driver marked the trip as accepted and then I return the driverFound() function; but if I iterate over all available drivers in the database and no one accepted my ride, then I end the search, notify the user, and return. The problem is that even if it does find a driver, it seems to return the driverFound() function; correctly, but after a while (after notifying all the drivers) it notifies that it did not find any available ones even though I previously finished the function

My function:

```
void searchDriverInQueue( BuildContext context) async {
  if(rideRequestIdAccepted)
    {
      return ;
    }
  getFareAmount();
  final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final driversQueueRef = databaseRef.child('driversQueue');

  // Ordenar la lista de conductores por horaEntrada en orden ascendente (FIFO)
  driversQueueRef.orderByChild('horaEntrada').once().then((drivers) async {

    final snap = drivers.snapshot;

    if (snap == null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "There's no available");

      searchDriver(context);

      // No hay conductores en la cola
      return driverFound();
    }
    else
    {

      Map<dynamic, dynamic> driversQueueData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snap.value as Map);

      print(driversQueueData);
      List<MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>> driversQueueDataList = driversQueueData.entries.toList();

// Ordenar la lista según el campo "horaEntrada"
      driversQueueDataList.sort((a, b) {
        String? horaEntradaA = a.value['horaEntrada'];
        String? horaEntradaB = b.value['horaEntrada'];

        if (horaEntradaA == null || horaEntradaB == null) {
          if (horaEntradaA == null && horaEntradaB == null) {
            return 0;
          } else if (horaEntradaA == null) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return -1;
          }
        }
        DateTime fechaA = DateTime.parse(horaEntradaA);
        DateTime fechaB = DateTime.parse(horaEntradaB);

        return fechaA.compareTo(fechaB);
      });
      print(driversQueueDataList);
      for (MapEntry< dynamic , dynamic > entry in driversQueueDataList) {
        String key = entry.key;
        print('DRIVER ID                    : $key');

        chosenDriverId = key;

        //send notification to that specific driver
        sendNotificationToDriverNow(chosenDriverId!);

        //Display Waiting Response UI from a Driver
        showWaitingResponseFromDriverUI();

        // Esperar 10 segundos antes de continuar
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));

        //Response from a Driver
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
            .child("drivers")
            .child(chosenDriverId!)
            .child("newRideStatus")
            .onValue.listen((eventSnapshot)
        async {
          //1. driver has cancel the rideRequest :: Push Notification
          // (newRideStatus = idle)
          if( await eventSnapshot.snapshot.value == "idle")
          {
            //Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "ELIMINAR MENSAJE EN PRODUCCCIÓN El conductor ha cancelado tu viaje...");

            /*Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), ()
                {
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Por favor reinicia la app.");
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  //SystemNavigator.pop();
                });*/
          }

          //2. driver has accept the rideRequest :: Push Notification
          // (newRideStatus = accepted)
          if(await eventSnapshot.snapshot.value == "accepted")
          {
            rideRequestIdAccepted = true ;
            //design and display ui for displaying assigned driver information
            showUIForAssignedDriverInfo( context );
            return driverFound();
          }
        });
      }

    }
    if(!rideRequestIdAccepted) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "There's not person available, sorry.");
      referenceRideRequest!.remove();
      AssistantMethods.cancelRideRequest("Not-found", rideRequestId, context);

      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => MainScreen()));
    }
  });
}
```

Previously there was no "driverFound" function indicator, it did a "return;" empty without returning a function, but searching I found that writing a return inside the firebase query, only ended up with that fragment and not the whole function, that returnning a function woeks but nope, so I created a bool global variable called rideRequestIdAccepted, but it doesn't seem to work either.

```
driverFound ()
{
  print('found');
}
```

Comment: What does the method driverFound do?

Comment: Just print "found" for test

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over the results of your first query (`driversQueueRef.orderByChild('horaEntrada')`), you make another call to the database:

```
await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
          .child("drivers")
          .child(chosenDriverId!)
          .child("newRideStatus")
          .onValue.listen((eventSnapshot)
            ...
```

The `await` here is meaningless, as `onValue` doesn't return a `Future`. All the `await on the` await eventSnapshot.snapshot.value == "idle"`calls inside of that block also are meaningless as`eventSnapshot.snapshot.value`also does not return a`Future`.

Since your `return driverFound();` calls are in an async listener, they do nothing more than return from the callback. They do not in any way influence the other loop that you have.

So what ends up happening is that your code opens listeners to all of the chosen drivers in quick succession, and then -without waiting for any of them to finish - it determines that no driver accepted the ride.

---

To fix the problem:

1. Use `once` instead of `onValue`, so that you can use `await` to wait for the value of each `chosenDriverId` before processing the next one.

```
  ...
  print(driversQueueDataList);
  for (MapEntry< dynamic , dynamic > entry in driversQueueDataList) {
    String key = entry.key;
    print('DRIVER ID                    : $key');

    chosenDriverId = key;

    //send notification to that specific driver
    sendNotificationToDriverNow(chosenDriverId!);

    //Display Waiting Response UI from a Driver
    showWaitingResponseFromDriverUI();

    // Esperar 10 segundos antes de continuar
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));

    //Response from this Driver
    var eventSnapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
        .child("drivers")
        .child(chosenDriverId!)
        .child("newRideStatus")
        .once();
    if(eventSnapshot.snapshot.value == "idle") {
      ...
    }

    if(await eventSnapshot.snapshot.value == "accepted") {
      rideRequestIdAccepted = true;
      //design and display ui for displaying assigned driver information
      showUIForAssignedDriverInfo( context );
    }
  }
}
if(!rideRequestIdAccepted) {
```

With this code, the `await` for the `once()` call in there actually blocks the rest of the code from executing, so the `if(!rideRequestIdAccepted) {` only executes once all the driver checks are finished.

As an additional optimization, you might want to stop search for a driver once you've found a match - but I'm going to leave that to you to implement.

---

The `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10))` means that you're sending the invite to each driver in turn, and waiting 10 seconds for each of them. You'll probably want to change that to:

1. First send a notification to all (available) drivers in a loop.
2. Then wait for one of them to respond positively, or all of them to decline.

That way the drivers are all asked to accept the ride in parallel, significantly reducing the total wait time for the user.

---

The entire problem is caused by failing to handle asynchronous calls properly, and using a realtime listener (`onValue`) rather than a one-time read (`once()`). I recommend reading:

- The Firebase documentation on [reading from the database once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_data_once) and compare the behavior to that of [listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_value_events).
- The Flutter/Dart documentation on asynchronous programming with [Futures, async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await), and with [Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams).

Comment: Oh thank you very much! It worked, I read the documentation and tried to implement the same approach in other parts of my code, and did it successfully, but there's a feature I can't fix yet, a feature that listens for push notifications from the user. that usage:
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? remoteMessage){
      if(remoteMessage!.data["cancel"] != null )
      {
      cancelTravel Request(
            RemoteMessage!.data["rideRequestId"], context);
       return;
      } });
As I use listener for notifications, I didn't resolve to replace it with once